# Why is snap rstore failing with "expected a non-negative integer argument"?

Tags: snap

I have tried to re-install a snap package and I want my settings back. I did a `snap save` before removing the snap. Now I am trying to restore the saved snapshot with `snap restore` and it's failing:

```
root@josh-workstation:/# snap restore lxd 1
error: invalid argument for snapshot set id: expected a non-negative integer argument (see 'snap help saved')
```

However I am following the instructions from `snap help restore` and `snap help saved`, so... what's the deal?

```
root@josh-workstation:/# snap help restore
Usage:
  snap restore [restore-OPTIONS] <snap> <id>...

The restore command replaces the current user, system and
configuration data of included snaps, with the corresponding data from
the specified snapshot.
```

Answer (score 5):

`snap help` *is backwards* and the actual command takes the ID *first*

It should read:

```
root@josh-workstation:/# snap help restore
Usage:
  snap restore [restore-OPTIONS] <id> [<snap>]...

The restore command replaces the current user, system and
configuration data of included snaps, with the corresponding data from
the specified snapshot.
```

Running `snap restore 1 lxd` worked.

```
root@josh-workstation:/# snap --version
snap    2.44.3
snapd   2.44.3
series  16
ubuntu  18.04
kernel  5.3.0-51-generic
```